# Literal quotes in flags for a command in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, quotes

I'm writing a Bash script in which I am running a perl script which requires flags that have double quotes in them. Running the script normally, you would run

```
$ perl script.pl -flag="something" -anotherflag="somethingelse"
```

In my script, I'm using variables in these flags, but would like to preserve the doublequotes, so I have something like:

```
variable=foo
perl script.pl -flag=\"something\" -anotherflag=\"$variable\"
```

when i run `bash -x myscript.sh`, I see that it *adds* single quotes around the entire flag, while maintaining the doublequotes, causing the perl script to error:

```
perl script.pl '-flag="something"' '-anotherflag="foo"'
```

I also tried `eval`ing the whole thing (`eval perl [...]`), and it stripped out the doublequotes altogether. How can I have Bash run the script with the doublequotes intact?

Comment: I don't understand -- the doublequotes in your "tries to run" ARE very intact, and a leading dash seems to have mysteriously disappeared (maybe a typo?) -- can you explain better what problem you're having? Btw, what's in the $variable, if not varoutput?

Comment: the leading dash was a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say...:

> Running the script normally, you would
>   run
>
> $ perl script.pl -flag="something"
>   -anotherflag="somethingelse"

...but then the shell running at the `$` prompt would remove the `"`: perl's script would never see them (they'd just have played their role of preventing spaces, and special characters such as '>', '<', '|, etc, from being interpreted within them -- those spaces and/or special characters would just be passed on as part of the arg). With the values as you're giving them (no spaces, no specials), those double quotes are totally useless and it would do absolutely no difference to omit them.

Anyway, if that is indeed the effect you want, just do in your bash script:

```
perl script.pl -flag="something" -anotherflag="$variable"
```

(or, omit the double quotes -- it's absolutely indifferent around `something`, indifferent around `$variable` if as in your example it's just `foo` but not in all cases).